# Assign categorical number to range of values in Excel

Tags: excel, categories, continuous

I have a column containing a continuous variable which I would like to categorize based on the value. This is a distance value. For instance, I would like to separate them into 50 m intervals (i.e, 0-49.999 = 1, 50-99.999=2, etc.) I am thinking this would be a simple IF statement, but I have not yet come to a conclusion in Excel. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sometimes I've used `vlookup()` function to do that.  You can put the values  of the range ordered in a column and the categorical number in the next right colum.  `=VLOOKUP(the_cell_with_the_value, range_of_2_columns_with_intervals, 2, True)`

Answer (score 0):

How about just:

```
=INT(A1/50) + 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had a feeling it was something simple I was just overlooking.